# PHP function progress bar

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, progress-bar, progress

i'm building some image convertor and the function i run may can take a while ,
what i want to know , is if there a build in way in php that i can use to show the progress of the function? the function based on the For loop (inside the function there are several for loop ) so i know in many loops the function going to stop.
is it possible?

an other question is that i want to know how uploading files progress bar work , if you have small example or tutorial it will be great ,
thanks , Mor.

Comment: Voting to close as not constructive. Please search the internet! If you google that problem, you'll find many solutions. Try something and come back with concrete implementation questions.

Comment: Voting to close as possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004258/create-upload-progress-bar-in-pure-php/8526071#8526071

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, to use `flush()` and `ob_flush()` to flush output buffering while executing script

Comment: interesting , i'm checking it out now , you may have example?

Answer (score 0):

Check thie out http://pixomania.net/dev/php/php-progress-bar-class